# In PyQt6 how can I call a function after every few milliseconds automatically?

Tags: python, pyqt6

For example in tkinter you could do that like this:

`window.after(1000,move())`

In Qt there is `QTimer`, but which method of it will help solve that problem?

I was testing a program which would move a label (QLabel variable) every 512 milliseconds in the QWidget object window (window=QWidget()). The coordinates of the label were saved in variables posx,posy. The initial coordinates were (0,0). I also created the QTimer object called timer (timer=QTimer(window)). I created a function for this which was as follows:

```py
def move():
     global label,posx,posy,timer
     while posx<50:
        timer.setInterval(512)
        label.move(posx,posy)
        posx+=1
        posy+=1

 ...
```

When I called this function then nothing happened except value of posx and posy changed to 50.

Comment: But in `tkinter` you would do: `window.after(1000,move)`. But surely you know that most gui frameworks are event driven and so manually writing loops does nothing for you.

Comment: You cannot use a while loop, because it would be either blocking or instantly completed. You should connect the `timer.timeout` signal to `move()` and, in there, check if the pos is less than 50, if it is, move it just *once* and update the pos, otherwise stop the timer. In reality, though, you should use QPropertyAnimation and also avoid globals.